# get last version or snapshot of a project with git, not whole project or clone whole

Tags: linux, git, github

I fork a project in `github`. now size of project when i do `git clone` is about 400 mg.
and size of `download zip`  from `github` is about 40 mg.
how i can get just last version/snapshot of project and continue commit, or remove all commits for every file except last commit from remote (`github`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git clone --depth 1 --branch=master git://servername/reponame mynewrepo` will give you the project without commit history.